# Chat App with Socket.Io - Difference between sending and receiving a message

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to create a little chat app for a school project, but I encountered a little problem since I'm really new to socket.io // node.js (coding in general). English is not my first language so I'm finding it hard to actually understand how it works exactly from tutorials.
Right now I have 2 css classes, one for the sent messages and one for the received messages. How do I make it so the classes will apply the right way for each message?
How do I check which message is sent by me, and which is received from another user? It's really unclear for me.

**Server side code:**

```
const http = require('http').createServer();

const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
    cors:{origin: "*" }
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('message', (message) => {
        console.log(message);
        io.emit('message', `${message}`);
    });
});


http.listen(8080, () => console.log('listening on http://localhost:8080'));
```

**Client side code:**

```
const socket = io('ws://localhost:8080');
const sendBtn = document.getElementById('sendBtn');
const messageInput = document.getElementById('messageInput');
const messagesContainer = document.getElementById('messagesContainer');
const chatBigContainer = document.getElementById('chatBigContainer');

socket.on('message', text => {
    const divEl = document.createElement('div');
    divEl.className = "your-message";
    messagesContainer.appendChild(divEl);
    const labelEl = document.createElement('label');
    labelEl.innerHTML = "You";
    divEl.appendChild(labelEl);
    let messageSent = document.createElement('p');
    messageSent.innerHTML = text;
    divEl.appendChild(messageSent);
})

sendBtn.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    if(messageInput.value === ""){
        return;
    } else {
        const text = messageInput.value;
        socket.emit('message', text);
        messageInput.value = "";
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you are not creating any element when you are sending any text. Instead you are emitting the same message to everyone :

```
io.emit('message', `${message}`);
```

and in that way you are thinking that you are actually creating HTML divs for both sending and receiving.
Firstly your server code should be :

```
socket.broadcast.emit('message', `${message}`);
```

(This sends to everyone but the sender and should work for your simple case with 2 users. Later you will need rooms)

This will show that you were actually not creating any elements while sending messages.

```
socket.on('message', text => {
})

sendBtn.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    if(messageInput.value === ""){
        return;
    } else {
        const text = messageInput.value;
        socket.emit('message', text);
    const divEl = document.createElement('div');
    divEl.className = "your-message";
    messagesContainer.appendChild(divEl);
    const labelEl = document.createElement('label');
    labelEl.innerHTML = "You";
    divEl.appendChild(labelEl);
    let messageSent = document.createElement('p');
    messageSent.innerHTML = text;
    divEl.appendChild(messageSent);

        messageInput.value = "";
    }
})
```

Replace the above with your classname and labels

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have two classes for sending and receiving messages? `socket.emit` will emit the message to all clients, and then you can append the message.

As seen from the socket.io chat tutorial (https://socket.io/get-started/chat):

[image: socket.io emit]

Secondly, if you want to check which users are which, you can assign a `socket.id` to users, like so.

```js
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log(`A user connected. ID: ${socket.id}`)
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log(`A user disconnected. ID: ${socket.id}`);
  });
});
```

This way, each user has a unique socket id. Maybe this can help you? I'm a bit unsure on what your're asking.